# Rewrite a file in an earlier commit then propagate that change to all later commits seamlessly

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

Suppose I have a series of commits like this.

```
(0) Initial commit
(1) Version 1
(2) Version 2
```

I already know that I can rewrite history without creating a new commit by using `git rebase` to edit, say, the `README` in commit 0. But how do I propagate that change to all newer commits? If I don't do that, it just looks like I had a section in commit 0 that I then later removed in commit 1.

Essentially I want the history to look like the change I made to the `README` was in fact always there from the beginning, without creating any new "merge" commits.

Comment: `git rebase` *does* create new commits; it just updates your branch head to point to the chain of new commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish what you want, you can use an interactive rebase where you say that you want to edit the first commit.

Run `git rebase -i --root` to get a rebase task list right from the beginning of the history (since you say you want to edit the initial commit).

In the commit selection window, set the initial commit to `edit` and the rest of `pick`:

```
edit sha0 (0) Initial commit
pick sha1 (1) Version 1
pick sha2 (2) Version 2
```

Make the changes to README and commit them with `git commit --amend` as you should have been prompted by rebase, and when you're done run `git rebase --continue` and Git will rewrite the rest of the history on top of your modified initial commit.

Warning: if you have any merged in your history, this operation will destroy them. If you do have merges you want to preserve, add the `--rebase-merges` option to that `git rebase` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `git rebase` to change the initial commit, then that change is propagated to the later commits automatically. If you use `git filter-repo` (or the old `git filter-branch`), then you have to make the change in each commit.

Answer (score 1):

> I already know that I can rewrite history without creating a new commit
> by using `git rebase` to edit, say, the `README` in commit 0. But how do I
> propagate that change to all newer commits? If I don't do that, it just
> looks like I had a section in commit 0 that I then later removed in
> commit 1.

That is not how git-rebase(1) works. Propagating changes is what it does.

To simplify things (so we don't have to worry about merge conflicts) let's
say that what initially happened (first commit to last):

1. Create readme
2. Add a source file
3. Edit that source file

The first commit has a readme like:

```
Project

<paragraph 1>

<paragraph 2>
```

You do `git rebase --root --interactive` and replace this commit with a
new one:

```
Project

<paragraph 1>

<paragraph 2>

<paragraph 3>
```

So you added an extra paragraph.

Finish the rebase. The change you did will have been propagated; you
replaced the first commit with the commit with three paragraphs and this
is the only commit that touches the readme, so the readme will look the
same in the last commit as in the first commit.

#### More complicated change: merge conflict

But let's say you did *this* in the second commit (before the rebase):

```
Project

<paragraph 1>

<paragraph 2>

Installation instructions: ...
```

Then you did the rebase and changed the file to this (on the first
commit):

```
Project

<paragraph 1>

<paragraph 2>

Usage examples: ...
```

Then you commit that and continue the rebase.

Now you run into a merge conflict on the second commit. Why? Because
git-rebase(1) propagated the change from (1), found a change in the same
part of the file in (2), then bailed out since it didn't know how to
automatically merge such a change.

This would not have happened if rebase merely changed each commit in
isolation; it wouldn't care what happened relative to the first commit
because the trees for commits 2 and 3 would be the same. But here we are.